# Is 'as' a pronoun or conjunction in these sentences?

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions

1. As you can see
2. As you know

What does these 'as' serve as? Pronoun or conjunction?
Thanks!

Comment: Would you like this question migrated to [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) (English Language Learners)? If you're interested in how to use the word "[as](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/as)", you might get more helpful answers there. If you're interested in how linguists analyze the word "as", then ELU (here) is the right place for it.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz Sure. I'd like to. How to migrate it to ELL then?

Answer (score 1):

In both the sentences, 'as' is used as a conjunction. 'As' is generally used as a conjunction, a preposition, an adverb or as a pronoun as in 'such as'.

For ex:

**As** you can see from the graph, fuel prices are consistently increasing.

(Clause 1: you can see from the graph

Clause 2: fuel prices are consistently increasing)

**As** you know, he is an author as well as a musician.

(Clause 1: you know

Clause 2: he is an author as well a musician)

Here, 'as' connects two clauses and is therefore used as a conjunction.

For other uses of 'as', check [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as) out.

Comment: Thanks, but [here]http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as says 'as' can be used as a pronoun. As to your first example, I think 'see' in clause 1 should be interpreted as being transitive rather than intransitive. I mean, you must see 'something' from the graph.

Comment: I just found that 'as' can be used as a pronoun as well. In phrases like 'such as' , 'as' acts as a relative pronoun leading to a relative clause. 'see' in my first example is intransitive as it does not have a direct object(see [something]). You can omit 'from the graph'(it's just an additional detail) to use 'see' as an intransitive verb.

Comment: There were very few sources that listed 'as' as a pronoun. I've not yet been able to fully understand this usage. Since M-W is a reliable source, I must accept that it was my mistake. Sorry!

Comment: @AishwaryaAR There is no absolute authority for these things. You can reasonably disagree with Merriam-Webster. I also find it strange to say that "as" functions as a pronoun in "such as". English grammar doesn't always conform to standardized sets of grammatical categories. Dictionary writers have to "force fit" the reality of English grammar, which is often phrasal, into a small set of parts of speech, which pertain only to single words. Different dictionary writers come up with different solutions to this problem, which are often incompatible and don't fully satisfy anyone.